# DAX IF measure - return fixed value

Tags: dax

This should be a very simple requirement. But it seems impossible to implement in DAX.

Data model, User lookup table joined to many "Cards" linked to each user.

[image]

I have a measure setup to count rows in CardUser. That is working fine.

```
<measureA> = count rows in CardUser
```

I want to create a new measure,

```
<measureB> = IF(User.boolean = 1,<measureA>, 16)
```

If User.boolean = 1, I want to return a fixed value of 16. Effectively, bypassing measureA.

I can't simply put User.boolean = 1 in the IF condition, throws an error.

I can modify measureA itself to return 0 if User.boolean = 1

```
measureA> =
CALCULATE (
 COUNTROWS(CardUser),
 FILTER ( User.boolean != 1 )
)
```

This works, but I still can't find a way to return 16 ONLY if User.boolean = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy in DAX, you just need to learn "X" functions (aka "Iterators"):

```
Measure B = 
   SUMX( VALUES(User.boolean),
         IF(User.Boolean, [Measure A], 16))
```

VALUES function generates a list of distinct user.boolean values (1, 0 in this case). Then, SUMX iterates this list, and applies IF logic to each record.

Comment: is it possible to pass in, VALUES(User.boolean) and Values(User.boolean2) ?
Need to put another condition in IF section.

Comment: let me know if i should open a new question.

Comment: If you replace VALUES(User.boolean) with 'User'  (the entire table), it will let you use any field in "User", although the code will be less efficient. There are other solutions, but it might be a good idea to post a new question with all relevant details and desired outcome.

Comment: you might want to answer over here too, or i can copy paste your answer over there, with linkback. 
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-IF-measure-return-fixed-value/td-p/689657

Comment: Go ahead and paste the answer there, and don't worry about the attribution - I only care if it helps someone.